# Problems while sharing images from ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: 22.04

After installing Ubuntu to 22.04, I experienced the following problems.

I've images (photos or screenshot) in ubuntu. From Ubuntu, i use WhatsApp, email, Messenger, etc. if i want to send photos or screenshots from these websites, they all tell me the file is empty. Unable to send photos or screenshots.

However, I can view them with the image viewer of Ubuntu

I tried to move .cache to .cache.old and .local to .local.old but that did not solved the problem.
Any ideas ?

Comment: I have difficulties to imagine, because your description is too vague and generic. Describe more precisely what actions you are doing to share the image with which applications, what you then see and what you instead expect to see.

Comment: I've images (photos or screenshot) in ubuntu.

From Ubuntu, i use WhatsApp, email, Messenger, etc.
if i want to send photos or screenshots from these websites, they all tell me the file is empty. Unable to send photos or screenshots.

Comment: Please edit your question and add clarifications to the question itself. Comments are only aimed to help improving questions and answers, may not be read and may disappear.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem seems to be the browser.

If I take a screenshot or a Gimp edit file, I can see the image file (PNG or JPG) with the image viewer but if I try to upload the file to any social network it seems the file is damaged/corrupted with size less than 1KB.

I was using Brave but switched to Chromium and I can upload image files now.